# Get input data from specific transaction

Tags: transactions, ether, web3j, java

I have a contract. I store data in ethereum using contract. Is it possible, to work with contract in git-like way.
For example, i have a list of previous transaction hashes. Can i fetch data from any specific transaction using web3j for example?

Comment: yes, but what is the specific question ? obtain data from transaction or specific value from one contract?

Comment: Gawey, obtain data from specific transaction. I can not add a comment unfortunately. It was me, who asked the question

Comment: Moderator deleted comment conversation. Hey! I can not comment to the first post! But anyways, Gawey, Thank you so much for your answers and links :)

Answer (score 2):

BTW, how i did it using web3j:

```
    Dto dto = new Dto();
    Observable<EthTransaction> observable = getWeb3().ethGetTransactionByHash(transactionHash).observable();
    observable.subscribe(ethTransaction -> ethTransaction.getTransaction().ifPresent(dto::setTransaction));
    return dto.getTransaction();
```

So, here is transaction with specific tx hash. Then simply getInput() to get data from transaction

Answer (score 1):

QuickBlocks (http://quickblocks.io) provides a number of command line tools that you might find interesting. You can do this from the command line for example:

```
getBlock 4100010
```

and it will print that block to the console. Or,

```
getTransaciton 0xhashhash
```

and it will print that transaction to the screen. Other tools include `getTrace`, `getReciept`, `getBloom`, `isContract`, `whenBlock`, among others. It's also a C++ programming library, so you can write code against it.

**Public service announcement:** I work for QuickBlocks.